# summernote - get a fixed text area

Tags: summernote

I am trying to use `summernote` editor in my application. I used height/minheight, maxheigh where I want to fix the editor and not allow  it to be resizable.

Here is the code that I'm working on:

```
$('#content').summernote({
  height: 400,
  minHeight: 400,              
  maxHeight: 600,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Summernote has the `disableResizeEditor`option. If you set this to true, you won't be able to resize the editor. This in combination with the height property gives the editor a fixed height.

For more info: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/95928611/

I hope this helps!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me...

```
.note-editable, .note-code{
    height: 350px; /* custom size */
    min-height: 350px; /* custom size */
    max-height: 350px !important; /* custom size */
}
```